# How to create a case object with case comment field in unit test?

Tags: apex, unit-test, case

I try to insert one record in Case object along with case comments, inorder to cover my apex class. However i got an error "Compile Error: Invalid type: CaseComments".Could you please help me how to insert case comments in case object.

```
Case cse = new Case();
 cse.Accountid = u1.Accountid;
 cse.Contactid = u1.contactid;
 cse.Description = 'TestDescription';
 cse.Status = 'New';
 cse.URLS__c = 'TestBiceUrls';
 cse.casecomment = 'test';
 cse.Subject = 'TestSubject';

 insert cse;
```

Comment: The way you described the question now makes it hard to fully understand the problem. Can you update the question with what you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Case Comment is not a field in Case. It is a separate child object to the case.

```
Case cse = new Case();
cse.Accountid = u1.Accountid;
cse.Contactid = u1.contactid;
cse.Description = 'TestDescription';
cse.Status = 'New';
cse.URLS__c = 'TestBiceUrls';
cse.Subject = 'TestSubject';

insert cse;

CaseComment cc = new CaseComment(ParentId = cse.Id,CommentBody = 'test');
insert cc;
```

[CaseComment SObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_casecomment.htm) documentation for your reference.

Hope it helps.